# Are polynomials on [0,1] dense in L1($\mu$)?

Tags: real-analysis

polynomials on $[0,1]$ are dense in $C[0,1]$

$C[0,1]$ is dense in $L_1(\mu)$

$\implies$ polynomials on $[0,1]$ are dense in $L_1(\mu)$???

Comment: Yes, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Comment: I'm assuming by L1($\mu$) you mean the space of $\mu$-integrable functions on $[0,1]$. Usually, one would read $L^1(\mu)$ as the space of $\mu$-integrable functions on $\mathbb{R}$, but with that definition your questions makes little sense...

Comment: You want to approximate an $L_1$ function with polynomials?

Answer (score 7):

I am very surprised no one answered this question. It has been years but I feel like people in the future might want to find this as a reference, just as I was looking for one.

By the Stone-Weistrass theorem we know that the polynomials are dense in $C[0,1]$. Thus for all $f \in C[0,1]$ we have $p_n\rightrightarrows f$. On finite measures we know that uniform convergence implies $L^p$ convergence. Hence polynomials are dense in continuous functions in the $L^p[0,1]$ space. Since continuous functions are dense in $L^p[0,1]$, so are the polynomials.

Comment: The issue is the same as seven years ago, I presume: the author never clarified what $\mu$ is.

Comment: @Gae.S. ah, fair enough. I will leave my "comment" since I think some poeple will still finding helpful.